# Is casting a shadow ray non-symmetric in pbrt?

Tags: raytracing, physically-based, global-illumination, pbr, pbrt

According to the [description in the book](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Introduction/pbrt_System_Overview.html#IntegratorInterfaceandSamplerIntegrator), `Scene::IntersectP()` "checks for the existence of intersections along the [passed] ray". This operatorion should be symmetric in the sense that if `i1` and `i2` are `pbrt::Interaction`'s, then `scene.IntersectP(i1.SpawnRayTo(i2))` should be `true` if and only if `scene.IntersectP(i2.SpawnRayTo(i1))` is true.

However, I've encountered the following contradiction to this expectation: For two `pbrt::Vertex`'s `x1` and `x2`, `pbrt::VisibilityTester{ x1.GetInteraction(), x2.GetInteraction() }.Unoccluded(scene)` and `pbrt::VisibilityTester{ x2.GetInteraction(), x1.GetInteraction() }.Unoccluded(scene)` returned opposite values. Since `VisibilityTester::Unoccluded` does nothing else than calling `Scene::IntersectP` in the previously described way (see the [description in the book](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Sources/Light_Interface.html#VisibilityTesting)), it seems like I'm missing something crucial here.

Comment: Could it be due to numerical issues for ray-triangle intersection?

Comment: @Hubble Well, hard to say, but I guess the error indeed depends on the surface the ray hits.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the visibility tester is inconsistent if you test on a scene with complex meshes with high-frequency details. Maybe try with two triangles facing each others, or reduce the robustness epsilon, and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: @Hubble I don't know if you're familiar with it, but I've tested it with the "sample.pbrt" scene in PBRT which is as simple as possible: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txaN0.png.

Comment: Huddle is certainly right: It might be due to numerical issues for the ray-triangle intersection. PBRT offset the spawned ray (https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/9f717d847a807793fa966cf0eaa366852efef167/src/core/interaction.h#L73) to avoid such issue. However, there is no silver bullet here.